# Code only working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The given code is only working in Firefox and not in any other browser.
I have given the Fiddle link for it.The code is working fine in Firefox and the functions are also working but it is not supported by any other browser.

The error shows is

> Error due to long Script

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkb2xrr2/)

Here is the code.

```js
var $boxes;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $boxes = $(".box");
  setupColumns();
  $(window).on("resize", setupColumns);
});

function setupColumns() {
  var $columnwrapper = $("#columns");
  var w = $("<div>").addClass("column").width();
  var cnt = Math.floor($columnwrapper.width() / w);
  var cols = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    var $col = $("<div>").addClass("column");
    cols.push($col);
  }
  $columnwrapper.append(cols);
  var cnt = 0;
  $boxes.each(function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo(cols[cnt]);
    cnt = (cnt + 1) % cols.length;
  });
}

$(".box").click(function() {
  if ($(this).height() != 100)
    $(this).animate({
      height: 100
    }, 1000);
  else
    $(this).animate({
      height: 150
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 114px;
  float: left
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="columns"></div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 1</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 2</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 3</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 4</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 5</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 6</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 7</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 8</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 9</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 10</div>
```

Comment: how to troll a stackoverflower put a infinite loop in a snippet

Comment: can you explain a little what you are trying to do(blow up) here?

Comment: I got stuck while animating the height of the div.There are multiple div with css float:left.When I click the particular div its height should increase.But since its height is increasing all the other div's position is also changing.I dont want them to change their position.What I want is that the div just below the target div should move down without affecting the other div's.

Comment: the loops at the beginning of the code what do they do ? from what i can tell they create multiple elements what use do you have for them?

Comment: I am creating a loop to make the columns according to the width of the window and appending each div in each column.

Comment: the code gets executed infinite number of times. thats why chrome gets stuck. debug the code well before you post them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to following line:

```
var w = $("<div>").addClass("column").width();
```

Apart from Firefox, in other browsers its returning 0 which causes `cnt` to become **Infinity**. That's why you are getting a really long running script that's creating infinite `div`s and adding them to `cols[]`

[Documentation for `.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) says:

> The value reported by .width() is not guaranteed to be accurate when
>   the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, ensure
>   the element is visible before using .width().

So what you will need to do is:

```js
var $boxes;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $boxes = $(".box");
  setupColumns();
  $(window).on("resize", setupColumns);
});

function setupColumns() {
  var $columnwrapper = $("#columns");
  //////////start change////////////
  var dummy = $("<div>").addClass("column");
  dummy.appendTo($columnwrapper); // add it to wrapper so that it gets displayed
  var w = dummy.width(); // this now returns 114
  dummy.remove(); // now that we have got the width, remove it

  // just to be on safer side:
  if(w == 0){
    console.log("column width is 0.");
    return;
  }

  //////////end change////////////
  var cnt = Math.floor($columnwrapper.width() / w);
  var cols = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    var $col = $("<div>").addClass("column");
    cols.push($col);
  }
  $columnwrapper.append(cols);
  var cnt = 0;
  $boxes.each(function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo(cols[cnt]);
    cnt = (cnt + 1) % cols.length;
  });
}

$(".box").click(function() {
  if ($(this).height() != 100)
    $(this).animate({
      height: 100
    }, 1000);
  else
    $(this).animate({
      height: 150
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 114px;
  float: left
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="columns"></div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 1</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 2</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 3</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 4</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 5</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 6</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 7</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 8</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 9</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 10</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is maybe because of cross-browser security concept by the modern browsers. If you are trying to run in Google Chrome. You might have to use the older version or install the plugin such as this:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en